VBA MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP 401 Unauthorized error
I am using getTokenTemp function to get token information based on ClientID, Secret and I am getting an error

401: Unauthorized

The same URL/client/secret information along with same header, if I put it in POSTMAN client, I am getting token information successfully. What am I doing wrong here? I am using MS Access VBA:
Public Function getTokentemp() As String
    Dim url As String
    Dim Auth As String
    Dim headers As Object
    Dim params As Object
    Dim tokenRequest As Object

    clientId = "CLIENTID GOES HERE"
    clientSecret = "SECRET INFO HERE"
    url = "https://URLHERE.com/oauth/token"
    Auth = clientId & ":" & clientSecret
    'MsgBox (Auth)
    'MsgBox (url)
    ' Encode Auth string to Base64
    Auth = EncodeBase64(Auth)
    ' Create headers dictionary
    Set headers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & Auth
    headers("Content-Type") = "application/json"

    ' Create parameters dictionary
    Set params = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    params("grant_type") = "client_credentials"
    params("x-sap-sac-custom-auth") = "true"

    ' Create HTTP request object
    Set tokenRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With tokenRequest
        .Open "POST", url, False
        ' Set request headers
        For Each Key In headers
            .setRequestHeader Key, headers(Key)
        Next Key
        ' Send request with parameters
        .send Join(params.Items, "&")
        
        ' Check response status code
        If .Status = 200 Then
            getTokentemp = .responseText
            MsgBox getTokentemp
        Else
            ' Display error message
            MsgBox "Error: " & .Status & " - " & .StatusText
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Clean up
    Set tokenRequest = Nothing
End Function

Function EncodeBase64(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim arrData() As Byte
    Dim objXML As Object

    ' Convert string to byte array
    arrData = StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode)

    ' Encode byte array to Base64
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    With objXML.CreateElement("b64")
        .DataType = "bin.base64"
        .NodeTypedValue = arrData
        EncodeBase64 = .text
    End With
    Set objXML = Nothing
End Function


Maybe this topic helps: HTTP Request in VBA using WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1, Basic Authentication 401 Authentication error

try using MSXML2.XMLHTTP instead,
let us know if it helps

Now I am getting login dialog. It should not show since I am already provide Client Id and Secret part of the request. any Idea ? Do you think encoding is not working ?
